# c# - how to manage CONTROL + digit on a TextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, keyboard-events, keydown, onkeydown

starting by saying I'm a newbie on C#, I would like to know how to manage on a *TextBox*, events like the **CTRL** + A, or **CTRL** + S, or **CTRL** + some digit.

*TextBox* has the method *KeyDown*, and I think I should use this, but I don't understand how to understand when a user presses first **CTRL**, then presses one random digit (still with pressed **CTRL**).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Sayse People simply downvote questions because it doesn't affect their reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `KeyDown Method` (or `KeyUp` or any other one dealing with `KeyEventArgs`) you can write:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
      //Both CTRL + E were pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm using this, it's cleare and it works for my goal. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` or anywhere

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
{ 
    //user is holding control
}
```